# How to fillna with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns A and B, there are some blank files in column B. I want to fill '0' in column B when column A = 'BC' and '1' when column A = 'DC'.

Current DataFrame :-

```html
A  B
BC 
BC  21
DC  
DC  18
BC  
DC
```

Expected DataFrame:-

```html
A  B
BC  0
BC  21
DC  1
DC  18
BC  0
DC  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
#df.B=df.B.repalce({'':np.nan})  
df.B.fillna(df.A.map({'BC':0,'DC':1}),inplace=True)
```

Or just

```
df.loc[df.B=='','B']=df.A.map({'BC':0,'DC':1})
df
    A   B
0  BC   0
1  BC  21
2  DC   1
3  DC  18
4  BC   0
5  DC   1
```